# Does CSS transform: rotate() rotate an image according to its aspect ratio?

Tags: css

I've been given this task as part of an assessment...
"The 'Rotate' button should flip the aspect ratio of the item."

To accomplish this I targeted the element and toggled a class name (rotate) and then added this CSS...

```css
.main-inner.rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

This works, however, I am wondering if this works with aspect ratio?

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm.... by the wording of the assessment I'm not really sure if its really referring to "rotate" as the rotate() function in CSS...

Comment: I think you should ask them what they mean exactly by "flip the aspect ratio of the item". Turn a 100x200 image into a 200x100 one?

Comment: @IvanS95, yeah I'm not sure either, I'll have to look into more what the rotate function is actually doing, thank you.

Comment: @IvanS95 Good advice, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```css
div.a {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;

  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>The transform Property</h1>

<h2>transform: rotate(90deg):</h2>
<div class="a">Hello World!</div>
<br>
```

Yes as this rotate function is developed by professional developers so it must does the related task like rotation

Comment: thnks for guidance sir

Comment: Html body and style tags are not required in the snippets. I've edited them again. You can confirm it that way. Thanks for your sample.

Comment: Thnks for kind information.yes i also try to explore nd learn new techniques.